# Callback for jQuery .on method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can achieve what I want with setTimeout:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#target', function() {
    // do stuff ...

    // ... then:
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do more stuff
    }, 300);
});
```

... but I was wondering if there's a way to use a callback that would be called after the event function has completed?

Comment: 3rd argument itself is a `callback`! What is your use case ?

Comment: You can use `$.Deferred()`, or `.promise()`, `.then()`

Comment: why do you need the timeout function in the first place?

Comment: do you have animation?

Comment: @madalinivascu Yes, css translate.

Comment: Do you have Ajax call in your first place `do stuff` ? .. if yes then call your `do more stuff` function in `success` event of your ajax call ...

Comment: @Prog, No ajax, just some simple hide/show

Comment: You can use `transitionend` event to call event handler when `css` `transition` completes. `$("#element").on("transitionend", doMoreStuff)`. Can you include `html`, `css` and `javascript` which effects `css` `transition` property at Question?

Comment: @3zzy https://jsfiddle.net/mLdsLye7/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize `jQuery.Deferred()`

```
$('#container').on('click', '#target', function() {
    // do stuff ...
    function doStuff(deferred) {
      // do stuff
      return deferred.resolve()
    }
    function doMoreStuff() {
        // do more stuff
    }
    var dfd = new $.Deferred(doStuff);
    // ... then:
    dfd.then(doMoreStuff);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use callbacks or promises, you can bind your target to run on a trigger, and then trigger that behavior whenever you so desire.

```
$('#container').on('click', '#target', function() {
  alert('I was clicked!');
  $('#target').trigger('shouldAnimate');
});

$('#target').on('shouldAnimate', function() {
    console.log('do some animations for target....');
    // do what you need to do
});
```

[Here is a simple jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/qkamettv/2/)

Comment: If you mean the jsfiddle, you have to click on the "Click me!" in the right hand panel. Or do you mean the solution? I'm certain it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to call a function when `css` `transition` completes, use `transitionend` event

```
$("#elementWhereCSSTransitionsApplied").on("transitionend", doStuff);
```

or if element is dynamically appended to `document`

```
$("#parentElementOfWhereCSSTransitionsApplied")
.on("transitionend", ".elementWhereCSSTransitionsApplied", doStuff);
```